# Asked for Captcha, but not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, captcha

I was trying to post an answer, but then it asked for Captcha to check whether I am human. The Captcha loader is shown, but the Captcha is not loaded and I couldn't post the answer.

When I checked the ajax call using the Developer Toolkit, it showed the request http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js?_=1383826516487 returned a 404 error.

Please check the recaptcha is working before showing the captcha.

Edit 1 :

When clicking on the submit in the question page a request is given to the url - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834440/answer/submit`

The response is as follows

```
{
    "success": false,
    "captchaHtml": "\r\n\r\n<h1>Human Verification</h1>\r\n\r\n<form>\r\n    \r\n    <div style=\"float:left; width: 460px; margin-right: 10px; min-height: 230px;\">\r\n            <a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvrva8NoMLM&amp;fmt=18\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n                <img src=\"//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/captcha-conchords-robots.jpg\" alt=\"The Humans Are Dead by the Flight of the Conchords\" style=\"width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;\" />\r\n            </a>\r\n\r\n        \r\n        <div id=\"recaptcha\" style=\"min-height: 100px;\">\r\n            <img src=\"/content/img/progress-dots.gif\" title=\"loading...\" alt=\"loading...\" />\r\n        </div>\r\n\r\n        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"s\" value=\"39cede1a-5a47-46e7-9194-74c65861c615\" />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <input id=\"btn-captcha\" style=\"font-weight: bold;\" type=\"submit\" name=\"post\" value=\"&nbsp;I&#39;m a Human Being&nbsp;\" disabled=\"disabled\" />\r\n        <br />\r\n        <div class=\"form-error\"></div>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div style=\"float: left; width: 350px;\">\r\n        <div class=\"module\">\r\n    <h4>Are you a human being?</h4>\r\n    <p>We apologize for the confusion, but we can&#39;t <i>quite</i> tell if you&#39;re a person or a script.</p>\r\n    <p>Please don&#39;t take this personally.</p>\r\n    <p>Bots and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days!</p>\r\n    <p>Enter the <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha' target='_blank'>CAPTCHA</a> displayed below, and we&#39;ll be out of your way.</p>\r\n</div>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <br class=\"cbt\" />\r\n</form>"
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that error exactly? Can you post the exact URL? Stack Overflow's [Captcha page](http://stackoverflow.com/captcha) is fine and is using [valid JS file](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_1-3d8ba004_89a6299c_995341cd_15b9c679_07496cd0.js)

Comment: Trying to answer the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834440/non-detailled-error-when-opening-website-in-ie7

Comment: Well, can't reproduce. Hope a dev will have a look soon and solve the mystery.

Comment: What browser? What OS?

Comment: The URL: http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js is currently returning a 404. Additionally https://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js has an invalid certificate, which will break lots of sites no doubt.

Comment: Is it not meant to be http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js?

Comment: @Oded I had this kind of issue at MSO about 4 hours ago, with FF 24 / Windows 7

Comment: @Oded  Google Chrome - Version 29.0.1547.65
Ubuntu - Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit - Kernel Linux 3.2.0-52-generic

Comment: Very strange - what do you see when visiting http://stackoverflow.com/captcha ?

Comment: @Oded - I can see the captcha there.

Comment: Good. Now, what page was it where you were not seeing it? On the question page itself?

Comment: And I can see the request in that page goes to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_1-3d8ba004_89a6299c_995341cd_15b9c679_07496cd0.js which works fine.

Comment: @Oded : Yes on the question page. I refreshed the question page and tried to post the answer again and the same error, Captcha is not loading.

Comment: Can you try emptying your browser cache? I suspect you have a stale copy of recaptcha's resources (we don't specify this url)

Comment: Alternatively - if you look in the source, you should find a url like `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k={some stuff here}`. If you browser to that url, it returns some json that includes the `server`; for me that is `'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/'` - what is it for you?

Comment: @MarcGravell : I tried clearing browser cache. Also I tried to post using another browser(FireFox) - the same error.

Comment: @Jithin can you try the url I posted above? (getting the `?k=` from your page)

Comment: I can't find a url like that in the source html. When inspecting the element, I can see the captcha is trying to load in a lightbox popup.

Comment: As I mentioned above, in the Network tab, I could see it goes to http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js?_=1383829484683

Comment: @Jithin can you tell me what you get inside the `<form method="post" action="/captcha">` ? when browsing http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha ?

Comment: @MarcGravell : When going to that page, I could see the captcha. And I can see the url in that page. Its http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc and the server in the json is http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/

Comment: @Jithin right; so where *can't* you see the captcha? what process were you going through when it failed? When answering that question, right?

Comment: I tried to answer a question. When I clicked on the submit, a popup box appear saying me to enter a Captcha. But the popup contains a loader image, which is supposed to be replaced by the captcha, I think. But as the request url returned 404, the loader stays there. Please see the edit above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they moved the endpoint. This only affects the **popup** captcha. Fixing and deploying immediately.

Comment: Yes, its working now. Thanks :-)

Comment: "they" meaning Google?

Comment: Hi. I had the same problem as OP, but it still keeps happening to me. The ajax call to get the captcha keeps returning 404 to me

Comment: @gonzaw I don't suppose you know which url is 404-ing? is it possible you have a block in place by a browser add-in?

Comment: The old endpoint had been deprecated since 2011. I suppose they finally switched it off. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/V7qswqBnA1o .

Comment: Hi. I don't know what happened, but now it didn't ask me for a reCaptcha and allowed me to post the question instantly.